# Number of Unique Visits in SQL

Tags: sql, postgresql

I am using `Postgres 9.1` to count the number of unique patient visits over a given period of time, using the invoices entered for each patient.

I have two columns, `transactions.ptnumber` and `transactions.dateofservice`, and can calculate the the patient visits in the following manner:

```
select count(*)
from transactions 
where transactions.dateofservice between '2012-01-01' and '2013-12-31'
```

The problem is that sometimes one patient might get two invoices for the same day, but that should be counted as only one patient visit.

If I use `SELECT DISTINCT` or `GROUP BY` on the column `transactions.ptnumber`, that would count the number of patients who were seen (but not the number of times they were seen).

If I use `SELECT DISTINCT` or `GROUP BY` on the column `transactions.dateofservice`, that would count the number of days that had an invoice.

Not sure how to approach this.

Answer (score 1):

This will return unique patients per day.

```
select count(distinct transactions.ptnumber) as cnt
from transactions 
where transactions.dateofservice between '2012-01-01' and '2013-12-31'
group by transactions.dateofservice
```

You can sum them up to get the unique patients for the whole period

```
select sum(cnt) from (
  select count(distinct transactions.ptnumber) as cnt
  from transactions 
  where transactions.dateofservice between '2012-01-01' and '2013-12-31'
  group by transactions.dateofservice
)
```

Answer (score 0):

You might use a subselect, consider

```
Select count(*)
  from (select ptnumber, dateofservice
          from transactions
         where dateofservice between '2012-01-01' and '2013-12-31'
      group by ptnumber, dateofservice
       )
```

You may also want to make this a stored procedure so you can pass in the date range.

Comment: I appreciate all three answers - all correct with a unique approach. The thing I did not realize was that it was possible to do a SELECT DISTINCT ptnumber, dateofservice to get unique ptnumbers per each dateofservice. This is a simple, direct approach that works amazingly well. Thanks.

Comment: @kipsoft Please consider upvoting good answers and accepting the answer that worked best for you! Glad we could help :-)

Comment: I'm sorry. I did upvote yesterday. Will try again. Not sure why it didn't take.

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple ways to achieve this, but you could use the `WITH` clause to construct a temporary table that contains the unique visits, then count the results !

```
WITH UniqueVisits AS 
   (SELECT DISTINCT transactions.ptnumber, transactions.dateofservice
    FROM transactions 
    WHERE transactions.dateofservice between '2012-01-01' and '2013-12-31')

SELECT COUNT(*) FROM UniqueVisits
```